# Why Mysql Data truncated error for VARCHAR field

Tags: mysql

Why on request :

```
update `customers` set account_type = 'SS' where `id` = 402
```

I got error:

```
SQL Error (1265): Data truncated for column 'account_type' at row 1
```

with table defined :

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`full_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`type` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`customer_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`account_type` ENUM('I','B') NOT NULL COMMENT 'I=>Individual, B=>Business' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`company_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`po_box` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`office_fax` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`vendor_details` MEDIUMTEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `customers_full_name_index` (`full_name`),
INDEX `customers_account_type_index` (`account_type`),
INDEX `customers_customer_type_type_index` (`customer_type`, `type`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1118
;
```

on Mysql 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
and how to fix it? Is it some Mysql options ?

Comment: It's not a varchar it's an ENUM with a single character set of values.

Comment: How do you mean fix it. Mysql in its own clumsy way is trying to tell you that ss is invalid for account_type and no there is no way to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account_type is an ENUM with alloweb value  only 'I' and 'B'  `account_type ENUM('I','B')`

you are trying to assign a value = 'SS'

You should assing one of the value in ENUM eg:

```
 update `customers` set account_type = 'I' where `id` = 402
```